# Why is my Label not Visible inside Frame in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create simple black border for a label in Xamarin forms.  It seems anything inside a frame is not visible.

Here is my code:

```
<Frame BorderColor="Black"   
       CornerRadius="0">
    <Label x:Name="txtText"
           Text="Here"
               TextColor="Black"
               BackgroundColor="White"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Frame>
```

I can set the background property in my frame to anything and that works OK, I even tried setting it to transparent with no success.

This is what I see with the code above.

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Android if that helps.

**UPDATE**

I've found a solution, but it seems hacky.  I've put it all inside a StackLayout, set the request height of the frame to 100 and set the padding to 1.

Here is the updated code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BorderColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColour}"   
           CornerRadius="0"
           Padding="1"
           HeightRequest="100">
        <Label x:Name="txtText"
               Text="Here"
               TextColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColour}"
               BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource SecondaryColour}"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: try setting the colors to distinct explicit values to verify that its not a problem with your resource definitions

Comment: I updated the question with hardcoded colours.  I get the same result.

Comment: @Noobie3001 Is this embedded in a grid?

Comment: In a ContentView.  I've come from the WPF world and am new to Xamarin.  I was trying to create a custom usercontrol (custom buttons).  I think the documentation said to use ContentView but can't remember for sure.

Comment: You can also try this out, instead of using `Border Color` in `Frame` try to use ` BackgroundColor="Black"` and `Padding="1"` in `Stack Layout`, and remove frame.

Comment: I think there is no property like BorderColor for Frame control. Remove BorderColor Property and try once. It will display your Label.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar [there is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame.bordercolor?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Frame_BorderColor). Took me about 6 s to look it up.

Comment: @Noobie3001 Could you show the whole XAML code? You said that the `Frame` was embedded in a `ContentView` but the image looks like something as a `Grid`, `FlexLayout` or nested `StackLayout`s.

Comment: Sorry about that  I was using Old version of Xamarin Forms. And it gives me error. So I have suggested that.

Answer (score 19):

Frame takes some default padding of 20 ,so if frame is really small then elements inside it will never show.
So,just make `padding="0"`.